# SF system tables for "credit usage"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do we have any system tables in Snowflake which gives us the credit usage information like :
a. Warehouse level
b. Account level, etc..

Requirement --> We have a requirement where there is a need to extract those information from SF via available SF connectors & orchestrate them as per the need of the client.

Regards,
Somen Swain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the [WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_metering_history.html) Account Usage view

Answer (score 0):

Credits used by each warehouse in your account (month-to-date):

```
select warehouse_name,
       sum(credits_used) as total_credits_used
from warehouse_metering_history
where start_time >= date_trunc(month, current_date)
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

More Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#examples-warehouse-credit-usage